# Android input language adding phonetic variation

Tags: keyboard, 4.2-jelly-bean, nexus-4

I'm looking to add a Russian Phonetic keyboard layout to the default list of input layouts in Jellybean 4.2.2.

Going into Settings->Language & Input->Keyboard & Input Methods/Android Keyboard->Input Languages

On that menu I see Russian, but it is the standard Russian keyboard which doesn't have Russian letters mapped to the English QWERTY layout.  There apps that do this but I lose the gesture typing capabilities for example.

I was hoping there was a way of adding a Russian (Phonetic) layout to the list by somehow modifying the standard Russian layout and readding it as a phonetic variation.

Answer (score 1):

After you've added Russian language to GBoard go to Languages, click Russian and it will show you additional keyboard layouts. Swipe right and choose the phonetic layout you like - there are even more than one!